# How to get lookup_url_kwarg in serializer of django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

this my Django view

```
class CreateForeignTableView(CreateAPIView):
"""
create foreign_table finally not difference a normal table ??
"""
serializer_class = CreateForiegnTableSerializer
queryset = None
lookup_url_kwarg = 'foreign_server_id'
```

I want get lookup_url_kwarg in my create serializer function

Answer (score 4):

Simple you can override `create` method to achieve this.

```
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context={
            'request': request,
            'id': self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

In the serializer, you can use `id = self.context['id']`

Answer (score 2):

You can override `get_serializer_context` method to achieve this.

```
class CreateForeignTableView(CreateAPIView):
    """
    create foreign_table finally not difference a normal table ??
    """
    serializer_class = CreateForiegnTableSerializer
    queryset = None
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'foreign_server_id'

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(CreateForeignTableView, self).get_serializer_context()
        context.update({
            "foreign_server_id": self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)
        })
        return context
```

In the serializer you can use `self.context.get("foreign_server_id", "")` to get `foreign_server_id`.

You can follow [this post](https://micropyramid.com/blog/django-rest-framework-send-extra-context-data-to-serializers/) to know farther.

Comment: thanks, bro , but self.lookup_url_kwarg return 'foreign_server_id' not id that I am looking for

Comment: What is foreign_server_id that you are looking for ??

Comment: /foreign_server/<init:foreign_server_id>/add_foreign_table/  ... iwant init:foreign_server_id that pass in url

Comment: Then this should work for you  self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to access the serializer `context`. **GenericApiView** sets the view itself into the serializer context, so you may access `lookup_url_kwarg` like this:

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
    my_url_kwarg = self.context['view'].lookup_url_kwarg
```